# Using Sql Management Objects (SMO) to connect to SQL, how can I find out if a view has any rows?

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I know I can find the Table Rowcount using SMO, but i'm having trouble getting the View Rowcount.. I dont really need exact rowcount (it is a bonus), but i do need to know if the view is "empty" (0 records).

Here is my attempt so far:

```
 public Int64 GetRowCount()
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString);
    ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
    Server server = new Server(serverConnection);
    if (server == null)
        throw new InvalidDataException(
            string.Format(
                "Could not connect to server {0}. Check that it exists and that the current user has access to it.",
                SqlServerName));
    Database db = server.Databases[SqlDatabaseName];
    if (db == null)
        throw new InvalidDataException(
            string.Format(
                "Could not connect to database {0} on server {1}. Check that it exists and that the current user has access to it.",
                SqlDatabaseName, SqlServerName));

    db.DefaultSchema = SqlSchemaName;

    if (db.Tables.Contains(SqlTableName))
    {
        Table tbl = db.Tables[SqlTableName];
        return tbl.RowCount;
    }
    if (db.Views.Contains(SqlTableName))
    {
        View view = db.Views[SqlTableName];
        try
        {
            view.ReCompileReferences();
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignored
        }
        return view.RowCount;  ************************** MAGIC GOES HERE
    }

    throw new InvalidDataException(string.Format(    "The SQL table/view {0} does not exist in database {1}, or is not accessible by the current user.",
SqlTableName, SqlDatabaseName));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is "no" unless the view is an indexed (or materialized) view. I say that because the SMO appears to be looking at the metadata in sys.partitions to determine row count and no row will exist there unless the data that underlies the view is persisted to disk. That only happens when the view is indexed.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, so I'm forced to do a query to see if there are records, because the information I want is not stored in the metadata..

Answer (score 2):

Just use Ado.Net connection to execute command:

```
        var cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"if exists(select * from {0})
                          select 1 as exist
                          else 
                          select 0 as exist", SqlTableName);

        var result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

if result == 1 then some records exists

Comment: i like it, but i was hoping to do it without an actual query, using the metadata SMO lives off

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find another way, you can always use the [ExecuteWithResults](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms205775.aspx) method to select a single row and single field. You can then check the results to see if it returned any rows.

```
 var server = new Server();
 var db = server.Databases("northwind");
 var results = db.ExecuteWithResults("select top 1 ID from [ViewName]");
```

Comment: this is a little closer, piggybacking off the smo connection to get a value.. i have no idea what fields the table has, so ID may not exist tho..

Comment: ID is just a sample field. Replace it with [ViewName].[ViewField] based upon where you are calling it.

Comment: Another thought is that if you don't care about the amount data retrieved, you could also do a select * from [ViewName] to see if it has rows.